# What is the relevance of has("autocmd") today?

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

#### Context

I have been using Vim for more than 6 years and have compiled it from source a couple of times during that period.  Over the years my `vimrc` did grow.  Now, I am trying to clean my `vimrc` and I came upon a dinosaur configuration:  `has("autocmd")`.

When I started using Vim I copied my first `vimrc` from a colleague and it already contained a condition with a call to `has("autocmd")`, as follows:

```
if has("autocmd")
    " ... several autocmds, most of them on the FileType event
endif
```

Vim (likely) can be compiled without `autocmd` support, and, I believe, during those days it was still possible to find a Vim instance without `autocmd` support.

Over the years some 60-70% of my `vimrc` migrated into that `if` block, and now that block is huge (300+ lines).  If I run a Vim without `autocmd` support I'll lose the majority of my `vimrc`.

---

On the other hand, I believe that `has("autocmd")` is rather irrelevant these days.  And, therefore, I want to get rid of that `if` altogether.

I looked through [Vim's `configure.in`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/configure.in) and there is no way to explicitly disable `autocmd` in there.  Looking through [`neovim`'s source tree](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/tree/master/cmake) I do not see an `Find*` cmake for `autocmd` either, I do not believe that `neovim` can be compiled without `autocmd`.

---

#### The Question

Since "relevance" is a rather opinionated topic, let's focus on the objective points of `has("autocmd")`:

- Under which conditions Vim can be/is compiled without `autocmd` support?
- Are there official compiled packages/distribution of Vim without `autocmd` support?  (Maybe on embedded devices)
- Both questions above but for `neovim`.

Comment: vim-tiny, often used as a vi replacement (debian, ubuntu I think), doesn't have autocmd support, or support for much. `if 1` is more useful in this case.

Comment: IIRC the first thing `neovim` people have done when they forked Vim was to drop support for all build modes except `huge`, and for targets such as Commodore Amiga and the like.

Comment: also vim-small package does not have autocommands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. If you install from your package manager a Vim with the feature set tiny or small, you won't get autocommand support. 
   Also if you compile your own Vim and disable autocommand feature in feature.h (or used the `--with-features=small` or `--with-features=tiny` argument)
2. depends on how you install Vim. Debian/Ubuntu provides official tiny and I think small packages.
3. don't know.

In short, that line is still relevant and does not hurt.

Comment: Well, it hurts plugin writers, but only a little.  Most of them have developed a Stockholm syndrome kind of fondness for these things by now. ;)

Comment: Cool, I now see the `AC_DEFINE(FEAT_TINY)` and `AC_DEFINE(FEAT_SMALL)`.  `neovim` does not use `~/.vimrc` (just learned that), so, yeah, leaving the `if has("autocmd")` will not really harm.

Comment: As the OP guessed, neovim will always be compiled with the autocmd features, and properly return `has("autocmd")`.